# What attacks can I block with the Guard Up Skill that I normally coudn't?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

Guard Lv. 5 already allows you to block truly ludicrous things such as a Rathalos' fireball or even the Nergigante's dive bomb attack.

There is however the set bonus of the Uragaan armor:

[image: Uragaan Protection - Allows you to guard against ordinarily unblockable attacks.]

What exactly is meant by an "ordinarily unblockable attack"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beam or gas attacks are normally unblockable, but can be blocked with Guard Up. This includes:

- Pukei-Pukei's poison cloud
- Radobaan's and Uragaan's sleep clouds
- Uragaan's fire cloud
- Kirin's lightning attack that hits a long area across the ground
- Teostra's supernova
- Vaal Hazak's beam attacks
- Xeno'jiiva's beam attacks
- Kulve Taroth's lingering fire pools
- Lunastra's fire puddles igniting from a different fire attack
- Behemoth's ground shockwave

Additionally, some attacks can not be blocked even with Guard Up, such as:

- Behemoth's horn impale
- Behemoth's Ecliptic Meteor
- Ancient Leshen's "bird nova", the attack that sends out Revoltures in all directions after charging up

Comment: Do note that there are completely unblockable attacks even penetrates through Guard Up. Examples include Behemoth's horn grapple, and collaboration monsters' novas (Ecliptic Meteor, crow storm).